# Spring Integration POST web service url mapping

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to make a POST REST WebService call
My outbound gateway is defined as below :

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="url"
        http-method="POST" request-channel="reqChannel"
        reply-channel="replyChannel" expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

My problem is with `url`. I need to have different url based on different conditions. How can I make the `url` variable configurable from payload rather than hard coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URI variables with expression(s) to replace placeholders in the URL...

```
<outbound-gateway id="foo"
        url="http://localhost/{foo}/{bar}"
     ...
                    >
    <uri-variable name="foo" expression="headers['foo']"/>
    <uri-variable name="bar" expression="payload.bar"/>
</outbound-gateway>
```